# Is there a word in the English language that means slightly surprised?

Tags: meaning, synonyms

Surprise can occur in varying levels of intensity and valence. Flummoxed, flabbergasted, astounded, staggered, startled, stunned, thunderstruck, aghast, taken aback, dumbfounded, dumbstruck, stupefied, dazed, gobsmacked, astonished, shocked, appalled, speechless.  These synonyms all have a heightened degree of surprise but none seem to define slightly surprised. The closest I think is jiggered, which is a British slang.

Comment: "Bemused" might convey mild surprise, but slight confusion too.

Comment: Are you looking for a catch-all term?  Because I think mild physical surprise (startled when an insect flies in your face) and mild intellectual surprise (stumped for a moment when someone asks a strange question) are quite different things.

Comment: Physical surprise: _startled_, as @JohnFeltz says. Mental surprise: _taken aback_. Don't use _jiggered_ -- it is very dated. (Also, _taken aback_ is a frozen form: you can't use it any other way. For instance, "This will take them aback" is wrong.)

Answer (score 5):

"Startled" carries a milder level of surprise than, say, "astounded". So one could be startled by someone jumping out at them, or by a cat suddenly swatting them with its paw when they didn't know it was next to them, or an unexpected loud noise. The meaning isn't just "surprise", though. Closest one I can think of, however.

Comment: "Startled" conveys a sudden surprise or shock though. It doesn't seem milder than *surprised* but yeah maybe milder than *astonished* depending on the context.

Answer (score 4):

'Mildly surprised' is how I'd express this idea. Sometimes a qualifying adverb plus the basic concept has to do the job of a precise verb.

Answer (score 2):

***Quizzical*** might convey the intended meaning.

> Chiefly of a person's expression: questioning, enquiring; indicating mild or amused puzzlement. *[OED]*

*He gave me a quizzical look when I ordered [toad in the hole](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toad_in_the_hole).*

Answer (score 1):

In the US, we'd probably say, "(Something/someone) ***raised eyebrows***".

Comment: i feel that rather means event X "was slightly outside of social norms; caused mild gossip"

Comment: @JoeBlow - As opposed to 'shock and awe'?  Yeah, 'mild surprise'.

Comment: Hmm, I may have expressed myself not goodly. "surprise" is when something happens suddenly - or unexpectedly. (Example: an explosion.)  "raised eyebrows" happen when something is socially unacceptable ("The professor married a student?  that will raise eyebrows"  "She took her fancy man to church - that sure raised eyebrows") It means it caused gossip; "surprise" may be uninvolved, the student or fancy-man incidents may have been completely expected and well-known.

Comment: for example, my computer OED gives only an example of social disapproval with no surprise involved ("Romanov merely raised his eyebrows at the discourtesy.")  (Although it does state the meanings as either surprise or disapproval.)

Comment: (I can't even .. formulate an example sentence where "raise eyebrows" means "surprised".  Example, "When the plate smashed on the floor, boy that raised my eyebrows" ... doesn't scan!)

Comment: @JoeBlow- I don't really understand the struggle w/ this... An explosion, (your first example) or a plate smashed on the floor, would not be things that would 'raise eyebrows'. YES, the expression is used figuratively - but it also describes a literal, reflexive facial expression that occurs when one sees something unexpected - or, SLIGHTLY SURPRISING.

Comment: Hmm, if you suddenly see a green cat, you go wide-eyed, you don't raise your eyebrows.  In "SHE WHAT?!" situations of social disapproval you raise your eyebrows.  I appreciate your point that "surprise" can be used to mean, example, "that Mr X won the election was a surprising outcome" or "her poor exam results were a real surprise" (ie, the results were announced calmly over hours and days, there was no "shock, startle" involved whatsoever, but the result was "surprising") -- fair enough. In any event you don't use "raised eyebrows" in either of those two examples. Only for affairs, etc.